# CSS: reset styles defined in an untouchable stylesheet

Tags: html, css, django

I need a simple `<hr/>` in a page that extends a default one (I'm using Django template framework); in this default page, a standard and untouchable stylesheet styles HR with `border:none; height:1px` but I would like to reset these styles to their default values.

I tried putting `{border:1px inset; height:auto;}` in my page but I didn't get the same aspect as having no style at all.

Is there a method to restore the default style for a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default stylesheet for HTML documents, without any overrides, is defined by the W3C. You can find the full default stylesheet here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Alternatively, you could use Firebug in Firefox (or any similar tool) to view the styles of an `<hr />` element on a test page without any styles applied.

Answer (score 4):

In order to make your rule apply, you'll need to ensure that you give your rule a greater specificity than the existing rule in order to override it.

For example, if the rule is this:

```
 hr {
   /* rules */
 }
```

Then you would need to do something like this:

```
html hr {
  /* your rules */
}
```

Scores are calculated by these basic rules:

- elements, like `div` are worth one point
- classes, like `.comment` are worth 10 points
- ids, like `#user123` are worth 100 points
- The total score for the selector is the sum of all of its parts, so `div.class` is worth 11 (10 for the `.class` and 1 for `div`

(It's actually a bit more complicated than this - see [this article](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity) for details - but this explanation works as a general rule)

**Edit:**

I just saw your comment about not knowing the defaults.

According to Firebug, an `hr` appears to look like this:

```
 hr {
   height: 0;
   width: 100%;
   border: 1px solid #808080;
   margin: 8px 0;
 }
```

You can use the tools provided in other browsers to see if they use a different set of styles, then decide for yourself which ones would be the best ones to use.

Comment: When you're explaining specificity, best to note that the scores are not base 10, 10 element selectors != 1 class selector. Instead it's a sufficiently high base that none of the "scores" roll over

Comment: @Gareth: Honestly, I've never learned how specificity *actually* works. I figure it's a moot point because if you have 10 of a given type of selector, you're probably doing something very wrong anyway.

Comment: @Gareth: I added a link explaining specificity in more detail than I could write.

Comment: ok, well it doesn't show that you don't understand it, because your explanation is similar to the specification's specificity (oo-er) description - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 3):

Try [YUI 2 Base CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/base/), seems to be doing what you want. Or even [YUI 3 Base CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssbase/)

There is a possibility to "restore" default styles only for a [certain context](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/cssbase/cssbase-context.html)

**Update**
Just checked - Base CSS does not include styles for hr element

Comment: I'm already using Django and jQuery... however, your hint is useful

Comment: Those links do not work anymore in this answer, updated link of `Yahoo! (YUI 3.5.0  2012) Reset CSS`: https://cssdeck.com/blog/scripts/yahoo-css-reset-yui-3/#:~:text=The%20YUI%203%20CSS%20Reset,build%20out%20websites%20and%20webapps.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need to give your styles a bigger weight; add an id to your < hr/>, or do this in CSS:

```
 html body hr { ... your styles ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You either have to not apply the styles in the first place, or override every broken style with explicit values.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give your styles more weight with the `!important` property.  If the original is like this:

```
.someClass { color: red }
```

You can override it with this:

```
.someClass { color: green !important}
```